# Managing Application Insights Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights

I'm wondering how application insights work with cookies because I'll like to understand user and session tracking, so I've been researching and...

Here is a brief introduction about the theory:

1. > Whenever Application Insights SDK get a request that doesn’t have application insights user tracking cookie (set by Application Insights JS snippet) it will set this cookie and start a new session.
   >   (from [apmtips](http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/01/02/application-insights-requests-tracking-more-than-just-a-begin-and-end/) )

2.

> **UserTelemetryInitializer** updates the **Id** and **AcquisitionDate** properties of **User** context for all telemetry items with values extracted from the **ai_user** cookie generated by the Application Insights JavaScript instrumentation code running in the user's browser.
>
> **SessionTelemetryInitializer** updates the **Id** property of the **Session** context for all telemetry items with value extracted from the **ai_session** cookie generated by the ApplicationInsights JavaScript instrumentation code running in the user's browser.
>   (from [azure documentation (Configuring the Application Insights SKD with ApplicationInsights.config)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config/))

So there are two cookies: **ai_session**, and **ai_user**.

And here comes my questions:

1. When are they initialized?
2. What is doing it?
3. How can I stop using them?
4. If I wanted to keep them, how could I change their expiration time?

Trying to remove them I made a project using ASP.NET Web Applications using the default template for Web Api, which includes MVC and Web Api.

Doing a research I found [this approach](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fb8afbd-091a-45c5-9d9a-c5ea512ad369/disable-user-and-session-tracking?forum=ApplicationInsights) to disable them but I don't have any WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule. So I commented out "UserTelemetryInitializer" and "SessionTelemetryInitializer" and this is what I have:

```
<TelemetryInitializers>

  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.SyntheticTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.UserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.OperationIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />

<!--<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />-->
<!--<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />-->

 <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
 <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.DomainNameRoleInstanceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
 <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
 <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.DeviceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />


</TelemetryInitializers>
```

And :

```
<TelemetryModules>

<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.DependencyCollector" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web" />

</TelemetryModules>
```

But it doesn't make a difference. Either I leave the modules commented or not, the cookies are still being generated.

Trying to remove the cookies, I commented the steps done in Startup and exclude from my project all the .js files, but the cookies keep appearing after every request.

So at this point I don't understand where the "Application Insights Javascript" takes place and I guess that what I'm missing is something in the backend. Am I wrong?

Finally, my commented Startup.cs looks like:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Try001.Startup))]
namespace Try001
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
         public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
         {   
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
         }
    }
  }
```

And my Global.asax.cs looks like:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        //FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        //BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Where RegisterRoutes is just doing the default routing. So I aimed to do just the very basic stuff to get it working, but I don't have a clue about where to keep digging.

Could someone enlighten me?

Thanks for reading so far.

Comment: "app insights javascript" is literally a javascript snippet that is in one of the template html/cshtml/master files, depending on the type of project you have.  did you add ai manually yourself, or did you use the "add application insights telemetry..." command from VS on a new project?

Comment: That was it, it was not the backend as I was guessing but the JS snippet in _Layout.cshtml. Thanks you very much for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: apparently i should have added that as an answer so alexb didn't steal my internet points! :P

Comment: @JohnGardner  a one sentence answer vs a full solution is not comparable ;-)

Comment: @HelloWorld well yeah, i would have posted more, i was asking a clarifying question, which you can't do in answers.  Also, the answer has been edited to have more content than it originally did :P

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cookie initialization logic happens in Application Insights JavaScript SDK. If you look in the source of your page you will notice JS from //az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js. You can also read/contribute to the source code of JavaScript SDK on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS

Replying to your questions:

**When are they initialized and what is doing it?**
They are initialized by JavaScript SDK when it attempts to send any telemetry item and checks if the cookie are not present, it creates them. For details see https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/JavaScript/JavaScriptSDK/Context/User.ts, there's also similar logic for session cookie.

**How can I stop using them?**
As of the more recent versions of the JavaScript SDK, you can now control the cookies as well as the local storage for both user information and the session buffer (used to rate limit the requests to AI) through the [config object](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md#config):

```
...snippet...
}({
    instrumentationKey: "<your key>",
    isCookieUseDisabled: true,
    isStorageUseDisabled: true,
    enableSessionStorageBuffer: true
});
```

**If I wanted to keep them, how could I change their expiration time?** There are two settings you can control:

- session renewal time - how much time elapses before session is reset
  with no activity (default is 30 minutes)
- session expiration time - how much time
  elapses before session is reset even with activity (default is 24 hours).

To change them set following values in this snippet next to where instrumentation key is set:

```
      ..snippet..
 }({
        instrumentationKey: "<your key>",
        sessionRenewalMs:<your custom value in ms>,
        sessionExpirationMs:<your custom value in ms>

    });
```

Comment: That solved my problem and taught me even more than what I thought that I could do. Thanks you very much for your broad answer, the code part just nailed it, really appreciate that

Comment: So is there no way to set e.g. AuthenticatedUserId and AccountId server-side, and initialize the cookie server-side? Isn't Application Insights missing out the very first request (as the cookie is only set client-side in response to this first request)?

Comment: There are options to disable cookies (and local storage) now, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md Set isCookieUseDisabled and isStorageUseDisabled to false.

Comment: Hi where do I add isCookieUseDisabled? To which file?

Comment: Config documentation has moved here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/README.md#configuration

Comment: is there a way to set the actual cookie attribute "Expiry/ Max-Age"? this seems to be around a user session itself and what App Insights deems as a worthy session to log or how long an active session should be managed by it for logging.