# Application Insights Cookies - Override Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, azure-application-insights

I'm using Application Insights to track information for my ASP.Net MVC application.

There are two cookies, **ai_session** and **ai_user**.

I'd like to override the value in the ai_user cookie with the application's username so it will be accessible in a TelemetryInitializer.

Microsoft's [recommended practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-send-user-context) is to access the username from HttpContext Session.  Unfortunately, the Session is not yet populated at the time the initializer is called.

As a workaround, I am able to access the cookie's value, however I have not found an effective way to override it where the updated value will persist for the user's session.

I found some information in this question: [Managing Application Insights Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280710/managing-application-insights-cookies), but nothing specific to overriding values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was setting a cookie value on the request instead of the response.