# How to remove cookies ai_user ai_session completely from client side app insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-application-insights, asp.net-core-1.1

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    @Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
</head>
...
```

When I remove the above code the cookies are still there in the browser (before I started debugging mode I deleted all cookies in the browser :-) )

I do not need the clientside app insights JS library. I use app insights only server side.

How do I get rid of those cookies totally?

**UPDATE**

I use asp.net core 1.1 and I can **NOT** update!

Comment: Please check the [Application Insights for web pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#configuration) document, there has a isCookieUseDisabled field, if this value is `true` (default is false), the Application Insights Client-side JavaScript SDK will not store or read any data from cookies.  Reference:[Managing Application Insights Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280710/managing-application-insights-cookies)

Comment: I know this link... it is pretty stupid to setup some javascript in order to configure it to a disabled state. That is pretty STUPID!

Comment: @HelloWorld, did you find how to remove these 'ai_user' and 'ai_session' cookies, maybe can you share how?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we use the [isCookieUseDisabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#configuration) to control cookies even though you think it's stupid.

If it does not meet your need, please raise an issue in [application insights github](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues).